# how to make vue firebase call asynchronous

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, asynchronous

I'm using amazon mechanical turk to hire some workers.  I'm using vue with firebase. In firebase I have the hits(mturk) and I want to close the hit when form is getting submitted in mturk iframe. The problem is sometime it closes the hit sometimes it's not.

```
public async submitAssignment() {
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
if (urlParams.has('assignment_id')) {
  this.host = urlParams.get('host')
  this.assignmentId = urlParams.get('assignment_id')
  this.workerId = urlParams.get('workerId')
  this.hitId = urlParams.get('hitId')

  const oFormObject = document.forms['mturkForm']
  oFormObject.action = this.host
  oFormObject.elements['assignmentId'].value = this.assignmentId
  oFormObject.elements['workerId'].value = this.workerId
  oFormObject.elements['hitId'].value = this.hitId

// form is not waiting for this before submitting the form
  await this.$store.dispatch('hits/closeHit', {
    hitId: this.hitId,
    workerId: this.workerId
  })

  oFormObject.submit()
}
```

}

Vuex action

```
const actions = {
  async closeHit({}, payload: any) {
    await db.hits
      .setDone(payload)
      .then()
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
}
```

hits.ts

```
  async setDone(payload: any) {
    try {
      return firestore.db
        .collection(collectionNamespace)
        .doc(payload.hitId)
        .update({
          open: false,
          workerId: payload.workerId
        })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error updating document: ', error)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you show the code of the corresponding Vuex action (the one that is triggered with the `store.dispatch` method)

Comment: I added relevant code snippets

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it causes your current problem, but this code seems like an antipattern:

```
const actions = {
  async closeHit({}, payload: any) {
    await db.hits
      .setDone(payload)
      .then()
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
}
```

You should use *either* `then` *or* `await`, not both. Right now your `then` doesn't do anything, but may be breaking the `await`.

Simpler and more likely to be correct:

```
const actions = {
  async closeHit({}, payload: any) {
    await db.hits
      .setDone(payload)
  }
}
```

Comment: I removed that part but that wasn't the fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following syntax

```
await this.$store.dispatch('hits/closeHit', {
    hitId: this.hitId,
    workerId: this.workerId
  }).then(() => { 
 oFormObject.submit()
 })
```

Comment: but isn't that the same thing?

Comment: javascript is non blockig, it will not wait to upper function to complete. after then(() => {}) will call after successfull execution of the same function in your case 'hits/closeHit'